# Pasting values from multiple sheets having error #REF not value

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have a problem with VBA code not pasting values

The code goes as following

```
Set rngSrc = .Range("D29")
rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
```

The problem is that I get only `#REF` errors since the VBA tries to paste whatever the cell has but I would like it to paste special values and I cant make it work with paste special function.

Does someone know how to make it work?

Comment: With `PasteSpecial` you'll need to copy and then paste in two commands rather than use `Destination`.

Comment: Could you please ELI5? I have no idea how to just paste the values.

Comment: Could I please `EL15`?  Well, I'm not overly familiar with `EL15`, but I could sweet talk it a bit if you want. :)

Comment: Explain Like Im 5 years old. That is how it goes. It is just I have no idea how can I get these values from 100+ sheets in just one sheet, but pasted not as Formulas that dont work but just as values.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but instead of the `Destination` method, you should be using `PasteSpecial` instead, check this nifty code below:

```
Private Sub copypaste()

    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your sheet name")

    Set rngSrc = ws.Range("D29")
    Set rngDest = ws.Range("A33") ' for example

    rngSrc.Copy
    rngDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

I feel like the code is pretty self-explanatory. Though if you have any questions, let me know

Comment: How would this look like in the large code I edited above? I am really new to this and I wanted to solve a problem that I have, I have like 100 sheets and I have to retrieve value from cells that are in the same spot in multiple sheets. And I have multiple cells I want to get, I just tried this with one

Comment: That's a lot of new code you have edited in. Almost sounds like a **new question** which should take this solution into a consideration *(\*cough cough\*)* and build upon it in a new [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your `CombineDataFromAllSheets` code should be:

```
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")

    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'These need updating on each pass of the loop.
        'Set them at the start, rather than before the loop
        'and at the end of the loop.
        lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
        lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst)
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

        If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then

            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

            With wksSrc
                Set rngSrc = .Range("D29")
                rngSrc.Copy
                rngDst.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With

        End If

    Next wksSrc

End Sub
```